# ASP.NET Core 5 Razor file compilation fails with two SDK installed for lower SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Using Visual Studio 2019, .NET Core 5 and .NET Core 6 SDK installed.

Verified running under development environment.

Create, run a ASP.NET Core 5 project using the `watch` configuration shown below or the IIS file changes are not recognized.

From Startup.cs in the ASP.NET Core 5 project

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var builder = services.AddRazorPages();

    if (Env.IsDevelopment())
    {

        builder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    }
}
```

Create, run a ASP.NET Core 6 project using `dotnet watch run`, make changes in Visual Studio 2019 or from Visual Studio Code changes are recognized.

Went back to the ASP.NET Core 5 project using dotnet cli shown below, still will not recognize changes.

```
dotnet watch run -f net5.0 --project ValidationSample.csproj
```

launchSettings.json

```
{

  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:6776",
      "sslPort": 44308
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    },
    "Watch": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
      "executablePath": "dotnet.exe",
      "commandLineArgs": "watch run -f net5.0",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Questions**

1. Is it not possible to have Razor file compilation in a ASP.NET Core 5 project with .NET Core 5 Framework and .NET Core 6 Framework  installed?
2. If I uninstalled the .NET Core 6 SDK, would I need to remove .NET Core 5 SDK and reinstall .NET Core 5 SDK or not?

In closing, I have searched for anyone with a similar situation but all I found where developers with issues getting Razor file compilation to work, nothing for two SDKs.

**Update 12/27/2021**

- Uninstalled .NET Core 6 SDK, tried again, no change recognized.
- Tried using [LiveSharp](https://www.livesharp.net/), tried again, looked promising, no changes recognized.

Starting to feel like a firewall rule which I have contacted our engineers to see what they think.

Comment: Hi @Karen, 1. The Razor file compilation works in Asp.net 5 or Asp.net 6 application. 2. Uninstall the .Net core 6 SDK should not affect the .Net 5 SDK, you can try to uninstall the .Net Core 6 SDK and check it. Before installing the .Net 6 SDK, whether it works well or not? And is there any error message?  "the IIS file changes are not recognized." Do you mean you are hosting the application on IIS? From your code, we can see that you are enable the runtime compilation in the Development environment.

Comment: Hi @Zhi, There are no error messages. This is a simple project, not meant for anything but test Razor file compilation as this failed in another project. Yes, environment is development. What I think the solution is to uninstall .NET Core 6 but when starting the uninstall I get a warning it will affect VS2019 and unsure if this is a wise choice?

Comment: I've added an update to my post.